# VSTS Deployment Agent: Failed to bind to CoreCLR

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am getting below `error` when configuring deployment agent (`vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1.zip`) on *windows server 2008 r2*, with up to date windows patches.

```
Failed to load the dll from [?1], HRESULT: 0x8007007F
Failed to bind to CoreCLR at 'C:\vstsagent\A1\bin\coreclr.dll'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your Windows Edition, make sure you are on **2008 R2 SP1**. The older version is not supported (See [.NET Core 1.x - Supported OS versions](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/1.0/1.0-supported-os.md)).

Just install the **[Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (KB976932)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842)** if it's not patched yet. Then try it again.

Reference the same issue in Github : https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/1174